# python execnet doesn't close channels

Tags: python

I'm trying to use execnet library in my project in the following way:

```
import execnet

....

gw = execnet.makegateway('popen//python=py -2.7')
channel = gw.remote_exec("""
                    from my_module import execute as my_function
                    channel.send(my_function(*channel.receive()))
                    """)
channel.send(my_arguments)
return channel.receive()
```

The code is working great and returns to me the expected value.
However, in my scenario, I'm executing it as part of a thread pool, and given X tasks that execute the function, all the channel processes (py.exe) are kept alive until the main process is dead.
I tried to change my_function to be the simplest as possible - print and exit - but the behavior is still the same.

Is it the normal behavior? What is the right way to close those channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouped Gateways and robust termination
All created gateway instances are part of a group. If you call execnet.makegateway it actually is forwarded to the execnet.default_group. Group objects are container objects (see group examples) and manage the final termination procedure:

Group.terminate(timeout=None)